# Plate captions overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, tikz-styles, tikzlibrary

I am trying to draw a probabilistic graphical model using `BayesNet`, a TikZ library for drawing graphical model in latex.  I have tried to insert plates caption - Tasks *i*, Classes *c*, workers *j*, features *k* - like the first image given below, but I cannot change the position of plate caption. How can I modify second image source code to change all the plates caption position like first image?

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{nips13submit_e,times}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define nodes
    \node[obs]             (y)      {$y_{i}^{(j)}$};
    \node[obs, right=of y]  (f)      {$f_{ik}^{(j)}$};
    \factor[above=of y,yshift=0.7cm]   {yf}    {Cat} {} {} ; %
    \factor[above=of f,yshift=0.7cm]   {rf}    {Cat} {} {} ;

    \node[latent, left=of yf]  (pi)      {$\pi_{c}^{(j)}$};
    \node[latent, above=of pi, yshift=0.5cm]  (beta)   {$\beta_{c}^{(j)}$};
    \factor[above=of pi, yshift=0.4cm] {pi-f} {left:Dir} {} {} ; %

    \node[latent, above=of yf, xshift=0.8cm, yshift=3cm ]  (t)   {$t_i$};
    \node[latent, above=of t, yshift=0.5cm]  (p)   {$p$};
    \node[latent, right=of p, xshift=0.8cm]  (alpha)   {$\alpha$};
    \factor[above=of t, yshift=0.5cm] {t-f} {left:Dir} {} {} ; %
    \factor[right=of p, xshift=0.5cm] {p-f} {Dir} {} {} ; %

    \node[latent, right=of rf]  (d)      {$z_{k,c}^{(i)}$};
    \node[latent, above=of d, yshift=0.5cm]  (gamma)   {$\gamma_{0,c}^{(i)}$};
    \factor[above=of d, yshift=0.4cm] {d-f} {right:Dir} {} {} ; %

    % Connect the nodes
    \factoredge {gamma}  {d-f}  {d} ;
    \factoredge {alpha}  {p-f}  {p}; %
    \factoredge {p}  {t-f}  {t}; %
    \factoredge {beta}  {pi-f}   {pi} ;
    \factoredge {pi}  {yf}   {y} ;
    \factoredge {d}  {rf}   {f} ;

    \gate {y-gate} {(yf)(yf-caption)} {t}
    \gate {f-gate} {(rf)(rf-caption)} {t}

    % Plates
    \plate [inner sep=0.3cm, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.2cm,color=red] {pA} {(f)(rf)(d)(d-f)} {$k \in K_i$}; %
    \plate [inner sep=0.5cm, xshift=0.2cm, yshift=0.5cm, color=blue] {pC} {(beta)(pi)(d)(gamma)} {C classes};
    \plate [inner sep=0.7cm, xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.4cm, color=brown] {pT} {(t)(gamma)(d)(yf)(y)(rf)(f)} {N objects};
    \plate [inner sep=0.5cm, xshift=-0.2cm] {pM} {(beta)(pi)(yf)(y)(rf)(f)} {M workers} ;
    \plate [inner sep=0.2cm, xshift=-0.05cm, yshift=0.15cm] {pJi} {(y)(f)} {$J_i$}

    %minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=3.0cm, yshift=0.4cm,
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable by adding a minimal preamble (enough to compile your code) and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If `\plate` etc. are custom macros, you need to include their definitions. If they are from a library or package, you need to include the code to load them.

Comment: It is not clear to me which caption you want to change so it wold be god to be a little more explicit.

Comment: @Andrew obviously the captions at the bottom, which are overlapping, i.e. `N objects`, `M workers`, `J_i` and `$k \in K_i$`.

Comment: off-topic: bravo for this nice `tikz` diagram in your first question!

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the captions at the bottom.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for the comment, edited my code!

Comment: Great! Thank you (+1) - saves the guesswork ;). I'm not familiar with the library (hence my ignorance of the commands) but somebody is sure to be better informed than me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hadn't seen that library before, perhaps because it is a third-party library, and not discussed in the TikZ manual. The only documentation seems to be a short readme file, so I had a look at the code of the library itself.

The library file can be found by running `kpsewhich tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex` in a terminal, on my system it is found in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-bayesnet/tikzlibrarybayesnet.code.tex`.

The `\plate` command is defined there as follows:

```
\newcommand{\plate}[4][]{ %
  \node[wrap=#3] (#2-wrap) {}; %
  \node[plate caption=#2-wrap] (#2-caption) {#4}; %
  \node[plate=(#2-wrap)(#2-caption), #1] (#2) {}; %
}
```

The caption is created by the second node, which uses the style `plate caption`. This style in turn is defined by

```
\tikzstyle{plate caption} = [caption, node distance=0, inner sep=0pt,
below left=5pt and 0pt of #1.south east]
```

So you can see that it is positioned relative to the `south east` corner of a node (`#1`), defined by the argument given to the style, i.e. `#2-wrap` in the definition of `\plate`. `#2` here is turn the first mandatory argument to the `\plate` command, i.e. the first one after the options. The node `#2-wrap` is a node defined with the `fit` option, and is a node that encompasses all the nodes given in the second mandatory argument of `\plate`.

The actual frame of the `\plate` is drawn by the third `\node` in its definition, which is a node that encompasses the caption and the list of nodes in the `\plate` (also via the `fit` library).

One way of moving the caption around is to redefine the `plate caption` style. As the library is written that has to be done before each `\plate` command with `\tikzset`. That is, add something like

```
\tikzset{plate caption/.append style={below right=0pt and 0pt of #1.north west}
```

before the `\plate`. Using `append style` as above you don't have to include the rest of the style definition, only the position will be overwritten. If you want to modify this for just one `\plate`, put a pair of braces around `\tikzset` and `\plate`, i.e.

```
{ % opening brace
\tikzset{..}
\plate{..}{..}{..}
} % closing brace
```

To late in the evening for me to try to modify everything, so in the code below I've only moved the `C classes` caption. Hopefully you can figure out the rest yourself.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Define nodes
  \node[obs]             (y)      {$y_{i}^{(j)}$};
  \node[obs, right=of y]  (f)      {$f_{ik}^{(j)}$};
  \factor[above=of y,yshift=0.7cm]   {yf}    {Cat} {} {} ; %
  \factor[above=of f,yshift=0.7cm]   {rf}    {Cat} {} {} ; 


  \node[latent, left=of yf]  (pi)      {$\pi_{c}^{(j)}$};
  \node[latent, above=of pi, yshift=0.5cm]  (beta)   {$\beta_{c}^{(j)}$};
  \factor[above=of pi, yshift=0.4cm] {pi-f} {left:Dir} {} {} ; %

  \node[latent, above=of yf, xshift=0.8cm, yshift=3cm ]  (t)   {$t_i$};
  \node[latent, above=of t, yshift=0.5cm]  (p)   {$p$};
  \node[latent, right=of p, xshift=0.8cm]  (alpha)   {$\alpha$};
  \factor[above=of t, yshift=0.5cm] {t-f} {left:Dir} {} {} ; %
  \factor[right=of p, xshift=0.5cm] {p-f} {Dir} {} {} ; %

  \node[latent, right=of rf]  (d)      {$z_{k,c}^{(i)}$};
  \node[latent, above=of d, yshift=0.5cm]  (gamma)   {$\gamma_{0,c}^{(i)}$};
  \factor[above=of d, yshift=0.4cm] {d-f} {right:Dir} {} {} ; %


  % Connect the nodes
  \factoredge {gamma}  {d-f}  {d} ;
  \factoredge {alpha}  {p-f}  {p}; %
  \factoredge {p}  {t-f}  {t}; %
  \factoredge {beta}  {pi-f}   {pi} ;
  \factoredge {pi}  {yf}   {y} ;
  \factoredge {d}  {rf}   {f} ;

 \gate {y-gate} {(yf)(yf-caption)} {t}
 \gate {f-gate} {(rf)(rf-caption)} {t}

% Plates
\plate [inner sep=0.3cm, xshift=0.1cm, yshift=-0.2cm,color=red] {pA} {(f)(rf)(d)(d-f)} {$k \in K_i$}; %
{\tikzset{plate caption/.append style={above=5pt of #1.north west}}
\plate [inner sep=0.3cm, xshift=0.2cm, color=blue] {pC} {(beta)(pi)(d)(gamma)} {C classes};}
\plate [inner sep=0.7cm, xshift=0.3cm, yshift=-0.4cm, color=brown] {pT} {(t)(gamma)(d)(yf)(y)(rf)(f)} {N objects};
\plate [inner sep=0.2cm, xshift=-0.2cm] {pM} {(beta)(pi)(yf)(y)(rf)(f)} {M workers} ;
\plate [inner sep=0.2cm, xshift=-0.05cm, yshift=0.15cm] {pJi} {(y)(f)} {$J_i$} 

%minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=3.0cm, yshift=0.4cm,
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another option could be to add an empty caption in the `\plate` command, and make a new node relative to the plate node, e.g. `\node [below right] at (pA.north west) {$k \in K_i$};`.

Comment: try kpsewhich on tikzmark too ;)

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Kudos for the clear and concise answer. I have tried your suggested approach, and it all worked seamlessly like magic. It was a great help!!

Comment: @percusse Had forgotten about `tikzmark`, but one difference is that `texdoc tikzmark` gives you a 'proper' manual, while `texdoc bayesnet` gives you only a short readme file. Still, 'undocumented' was perhaps a too strong word.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with the same repo and faced this issue. After a close inspection of the repo, I found that another solution is to simply include the plate label inside arguments for the new plate. This ensures that the captions are not superimposed.

Do something like this:

```
\plate {A} {(a)} {$M$} ;
\plate {B} {(b)(A)} {$N$} ;
```

Instead of :

```
\plate {A} {(a)} {$M$} ;
\plate {B} {(b)(a)} {$N$} ;
```

Comment: Welcome! Er ... what's the difference exactly?

Comment: @cfr, in the second row it is `A` instead of `a`.